# constant vertex ids in adjacency_list

Tags: boost, graph, boost-graph, adjacency-list

I would like to keep external properties for vertices and edges of an adjacency_list graph (and for groups of vertices). I need to be able to access vertices by their properties. 
For example, I would like to iterate over all vertices assigned some weight, and get their out edges.

However, I also need my vertex container to be setS. 
In this container, adding \ removing a vertex may invalidate the vertex descriptors.

The problem is that the external properties could now be mapped to invalid vertex_descriptors.

```
    class manage_data {
...
    auto get_interesting(int weight) {
        return ver_by_weight.equal_range(weight);
    }
    void do_stuff (...) {
        auto for_later_use = get_interesting();
        ...
        boost::remove_vertex(unrelated_vertex, graph_);
        ...
        use_vec(for_later_use.front()); //bug
    }
    }
```

One approach seems to be to add a vertex_index property. This doesn't work, as it is one directional- you could get the vertex_index via the vertex_descriptor, but not the other way round.  This means I can't add an edge between two vertices that I only know the index of.

Another promising solution was using a labeled graph. This graph can add edges only by labels. I could have gotten pretty far by storing external data with a label id. Unfortunately, not all of the adjacency_list interface is reimplemented using labels - e.g. out_edges. This means I still need to be able to access the vertex descriptor, and it is impossible (in reasonable time) using only the label, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902294/get-node-label-from-boostlabeled-graph)

An even better solution will be to combine the above two - have a vertex_label property. This seems overly complex, and it doesn't work (above example).

Shouldn't it be common for vertices to relate to external data? How can you do it?

Comment: "all vertices assigned some weight" - did you mean edges?

Comment: no, as in the example code - ver_by_weight.equal_range(weight) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bidirectional mapping from vertex-descriptor to your own ID.

Now, as long as you use any node-based container selector for the vertex container, you're all set.

Have a look at BiMap and possibly `transform_value_property_map` for maximum convenience (although you might not require all the fancies especially if the graph is mostly read-only - or shrink-only e.g.)

See also

- [BGL indexing a vertex by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296206/bgl-indexing-a-vertex-by-keys/32296688#32296688)
- [Weight map as function in Boost Graph Dijkstra algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103659/weight-map-as-function-in-boost-graph-dijkstra-algorithm/33104513#33104513)
- [How to use boost::graph dijkstra's algorithm if vertex properties are pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847186/how-to-use-boostgraph-dijkstras-algorithm-if-vertex-properties-are-pointers/41858441#41858441)

Comment: How can i use a bidirectional mapping, when vertex-descriptor become invalid? I can only use inner properties, so the graph class will update my vertex-descriptor. Does BGL have an inner bidirectional property?

Comment: what is a node-based container selector ? :)

Comment: Node based is when allocation of the data-structure uses nodes. So, `listS` or `setS` would do. "when vertex-descriptor become invalid" - they don't¹ when using these node-based containers. (¹ Only actually deleted descriptors become invalid)

Comment: Great. Then these containers where exactly what I was looking for .